# Add metadata to a file using javascript to uniquely identify a file

Tags: javascript, metadata, file-handling

As part of a project, I want to **uniquely identify any file** passed to a specific function. The file can be of **any type**. Is there any way to identify a file like that? Or,  I was thinking about **adding some metadata** (an ID number) to the file. Is there a method in **javascript** to add **user-defined metadata** to any file?

Comment: Depending on file size you can store the file as a `data URI` as a value at `JSON`, convert `JSON` to a JavaScript object to get key, value pairs of the object.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But for large files, it will take long time, right?

Comment: @MatthewGeorge What are "large files" and "long time"?

Comment: I am trying to implement this in a web app. So, if we're taking about large files, say of 2 GB. Its going to take a minute or so at least, right? Isn't it a bit long for the user?

Comment: Not sure if a `data URL` representation of a 2GB+ file can be achieved at all browsers. Not certain about the exact length of time the procedure would take.